# Configure WSO2 ESB JMS Transport with IBM Messagesight

Tags: jms, wso2, wso2-esb

I was wondering how to configure a JMS transport to work with IBM MessageSight, similar to: http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB460/Configure+with+ActiveMQ

Right now, I have the following in axis2.xml:

```
  <transportReceiver name="ibmMsgSightJMS" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener">
       <parameter name="myTopicConnectionFactory" locked="false">
           <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.ibm.ima.jms.ImaJmsFactory</parameter>
           <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">tcp://192.168.154.128:1883</parameter>
           <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">TopicConnectionFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">topic</parameter>
       </parameter>

       <parameter name="myQueueConnectionFactory" locked="false">
           <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.ibm.ima.jms.ImaJmsFactory</parameter>
           <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">tcp://192.168.154.128:1883</parameter>
           <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
       </parameter>
       <parameter name="default" locked="false">
           <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.ibm.ima.jms.ImaJmsFactory</parameter>
           <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">tcp://192.168.154.128:1883</parameter>
           <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
       </parameter>
   </transportReceiver>
```

And I have something like this in an ESB proxy service:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="esbProcessMqttJMSPS" statistics="disable" trace="disable" transports="ibmMsgSightJMS">
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConcurrentConsumers">1</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">myTopicConnectionFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">B</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">B</parameter>
</proxy>
```

When I startup the ESB server, I get the following error: Cannot acquire JNDI context, JMS Connection factory : TopicConnectionFactory or default destination : null for JMS CF

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: In your proxy service, "transport.jms.DestinationType" should be 'topic'. Transport destination type accepted value is either 'queue' or 'topic'.  Can you check with above changes? http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/transports/jms.html#Service_configuration: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/transports/jms.html#Service_configuration

Comment: good call - I was playing around with stuff and forgot to change that back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured this out.

The jms config in axis2.xml should be:

```
   <transportReceiver name="ibmMsgSightJMS" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener">
       <parameter name="myTopicConnectionFactory">
           <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>
           <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">file:/C:/path/to/wso2/repository/conf/jndi</parameter>
           <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">connFactory1</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">topic</parameter>
       </parameter>

       <parameter name="myQueueConnectionFactory">
           <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>
           <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">file:/C:/path/to/wso2/repository/conf/jndi</parameter>
           <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">connFactory1</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType">queue</parameter>
       </parameter>

       <parameter name="default">
           <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>
           <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">file:/C:/path/to/wso2/repository/conf/jndi</parameter>
           <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">connFactory1</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType">topic</parameter>
       </parameter>
   </transportReceiver>
```

And I have a jndi properties file named .bindings with the following:

```
connFactory1/ClassName=com.ibm.ima.jms.impl.ImaConnectionFactory
connFactory1/FactoryName=com.ibm.ima.jms.impl.ImaConnectionFactory
connFactory1/RefAddr/0/Encoding=String
connFactory1/RefAddr/0/Type=Port
connFactory1/RefAddr/0/Content=16102
connFactory1/RefAddr/1/Encoding=String
connFactory1/RefAddr/1/Type=Server
connFactory1/RefAddr/1/Content=192.168.154.128
connFactory1/RefAddr/2/Encoding=String
connFactory1/RefAddr/2/Content=common
connFactory1/RefAddr/2/Type=ObjectType
RequestTopic/ClassName=com.ibm.ima.jms.impl.ImaTopic
RequestTopic/FactoryName=com.ibm.ima.jms.impl.ImaTopic
RequestTopic/RefAddr/0/Encoding=String
RequestTopic/RefAddr/0/Type=Name
RequestTopic/RefAddr/0/Content=testRequestTopic
ResponseTopic/ClassName=com.ibm.ima.jms.impl.ImaTopic
ResponseTopic/FactoryName=com.ibm.ima.jms.impl.ImaTopic
ResponseTopic/RefAddr/0/Encoding=String
ResponseTopic/RefAddr/0/Type=Name
ResponseTopic/RefAddr/0/Content=testResponseTopic
```

Also, don't forget to put the ImaJmsClient.jar inside components/lib.

I am still having issues where every service is creating topics/queues, and because they are not defined in .bindings, the server is puking.  I have worked around this by removing the jms transport protocol on every data service and jar service.