# Error while trying to connect to jms connection factory

Tags: wso2, queue, jms, activemq-classic, wso2-micro-integrator

```
myQueueSender org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.AxisJMSException: Cannot acquire JNDI context, 
JMS Connection factory : QueueConnectionFactory or default destination : null for JMS CF : 
myQueueSender using : {transport.jms.UserName=wso2user, 
transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType=queue, transport.jms.Password=***, 
transport.jms.CacheLevel=producer, java.naming.provider.url=failover:tcp://10.197.41.147:61616, 
transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory, 
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory}
```

Getting this error when I start the server. here is the configuration:

```
parameter.username = "wso2custiomer"
 parameter.password = "123456abcd"
 parameter.initial_naming_factory = "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"
 parameter.provider_url = "failover:tcp://10.197.41.147:61616"
 parameter.connection_factory_name = "QueueConnectionFactory"
 parameter.connection_factory_type = "queue"
 parameter.cache_level = "producer"
```

Comment: Is that the full error?

Comment: @ycr yes this is the full error

Comment: @WajihHaider Did you try this?https://stackoverflow.com/q/20010400